# How do I make an arrows, texts and dots in my own TikZ graph

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-arrows, tikz-graphs

Following the advice of @cfr, I have made the graph the TikZ from 0 guiding me through several pdf and TikZ graphs from other approaches.

Here my TikZ LaTex:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[
  ell/.style 2 args={
    ellipse,
    minimum width=2.4cm,
    minimum height=1cm,
    draw,
    label={[name=#1]center:#2}
  },
  connection/.style={thick,densely dotted, latex-latex}
]

\node [ell={A}{A },   fill=green!20] (a) at (1.5,1.0) {};
\node [ell={B}{B},   fill=blue!20]  (b) at (1.5,-0.5) {};
\node [ell={C}{C},   fill=blue!20]  (c) at (1.5,-2.0) {};
\node [ell={D}{D},   fill=blue!20]  (d) at (1.5,-3.5) {};
\node [ell={E}{E},   fill=blue!20]  (e) at (1.5,-5.0) {};

\node [ell={F}{F},   fill=blue!20]  (f) at (1.5,-8.0) {};
\node [ell={G}{G},   fill=blue!20]  (g) at (1.5,-9.5) {};
\node [ell={H}{H},   fill=blue!20]  (h) at (1.5,-11.0) {};



\node [ell={I}{I},fill=red!20]   (i) at (9.5, 1.0) {};
\node [ell={J}{J},fill=red!20]   (j) at (9.5,-0.5) {};
\node [ell={K}{K},fill=red!20]   (k) at (9.5,-2.0) {};
\node [ell={L}{L},fill=red!20]   (l) at (9.5,-3.5) {};
\node [ell={M}{M},fill=red!20]   (m) at (9.5,-5.0) {};

\node [ell={N}{N},fill=red!20]   (n) at (9.5,-8.0) {};
\node [ell={O}{O},fill=red!20]   (o) at (9.5,-9.5) {};
\node [ell={P}{P},fill=red!20]   (p) at (9.5,-11.0) {};


\draw [->] (A)->(I);
\draw [->] (K)->(B);
\draw [->] (B)->(L);
\draw [->] (L)->(C);
\draw [->] (E)->(M);


\draw [->] (E)->(M);

\draw [dotted] (E)->(F);
\draw [dotted] (M)->(N);


\draw [->] (G)->(N);
\draw [->] (P)->(H);


\draw [-latex] (i.10) to[bend left] (j.5);
\draw [-latex] (j.10) to[bend left] (k.5);

\draw [-latex] (c.180) to[bend right] (d. -180);
\draw [-latex] (d.180) to[bend right] (e. -180);

\draw [-latex] (f.180) to[bend right] (g. -180);


\draw [-latex] (n.10) to[bend left] (o.5);
\draw [-latex] (o.10) to[bend left] (p.5);



%\draw [-latex] (a.300) to[bend right] (b.150);
\end{tikzpicture}
```

and I tried to do the 1st line at the beginning, which says "pH1" and the other 2 lines with ellipses in the middle and the text "rho", how can I add those two things?

[image]

regards again,
M

Comment: Welcome! Questions which just post an image and ask how to draw it are not really fair or reasonable for this site. Please post some code showing what you've got and explain the particular problem you are having. I don't know what you mean about which 'concepts' you should use. You mean graph theory? That's really off-topic. However, the Ti*k*Z manual has examples similar-looking and so does this site and the PGF/Ti*k*Z example site and .... You may get lucky - especially if you change the image you want to include a duck - and someone do your work for you. But posting code is a better option.

Comment: Hello @cfr, thank you for your comment, I appreciate it, I pay attention to you and below I leave my progress with a real doubt.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

with use of `tikz` libraries `calc`, `chains`, `positioning` and `quotes`:

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=3mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{calc, chains, positioning, quotes, shapes}


\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[auto=right,
    node distance = 3mm and 18mm,
      start chain = going below,
    mynode/.style = {ellipse, draw, fill=cyan!70,
                     minimum width=12mm, inner sep=1pt,
                     on chain}
                        ]
\foreach \i [count=\j] in {A,B,C,D,E,n,F,G,H}
{
\ifnum\j=6
  \node[on chain] (\i) {$\vdots$}
\else
    \node[mynode] (\i) {\i}
\fi;
}
\node[mynode, right=of A] (I) {I};
\foreach \i [count=\j from 0] in {J,K,L,M,n,N,O,P}
{
\ifnum\j=4
  \node[on chain] (\i) {$\vdots$}
\else
    \node[mynode] (\i) {\i}
\fi;
}
%
\coordinate[above=of $(A)!0.5!(I)$, label=pH1] (in);
%
\draw[-latex]   (in) edge (A)
                (A) edge (I)
                (B) edge (L)
                (K) edge (B)
                (L) edge (C)
                (E) edge (M)
                (M) edge (E)
                (G) edge (N)
                (P) edge (H)
                (C.west) edge [bend right] (D.west)
                (D.west) edge [bend right] (E.west)
                (F.west) edge [bend right] (G.west)
                (I.east) edge [bend left]  (J.east)
                (J.east) edge [bend left]  (K.east)
                (N.east) edge [bend left]  (O.east)
                (O.east)  to  [bend left]  (P.east);
\path (M) to coordinate[pos=0.3] (aux-1) coordinate[pos=0.7] (aux-2) (F);
\draw[-latex]   (M) -- (aux-1)
                (aux-2)-- (F);
\draw[dotted]    (aux-1) to ["rho"] (aux-2);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

Please don't complain about the color of the nodes. ;-)

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=5]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes,calc}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[murmel/.style={shape=ellipse,fill=blue!70!yellow!20!green!40, 
minimum width=2cm,minimum height=0.5cm, draw,inner sep=0pt,align=center,text
width=1.9cm}]
\foreach \i [count=\y] in {A,...,H}
  \node[murmel] (\i) at (0,-\y) { \i};
\foreach \i [count=\y] in {I,...,M}
  \node[murmel] (\i) at (5,-\y) { \i};
\foreach \i [count=\y] in {N,...,P}
  \node[murmel] (\i) at ($(5,-\y)+(0,-6)$) { \i};
\draw[-latex,bend right](C.west) to (D.west);
\draw[-latex,bend right](D.west) to (E.west);
\draw[-latex,bend right](F.west) to (G.west);
\draw[-latex,bend left](I.east) to (J.east);
\draw[-latex,bend left](J.east) to (K.east);
\draw[-latex,bend left](N.east) to (O.east);
\draw[-latex,bend left](O.east) to (P.east);
\draw[-latex](A.east) -- (I.west);
\draw[-latex](K.west) -- (B.east);
\draw[-latex](B.east) -- (L.west);
\draw[-latex](L.west) -- (C.east);
\draw[latex-latex](M.west) -- (E.east);
\draw[-latex](M.west) -- (F.east);
\draw[-latex](G.east) -- (N.west);
\draw[-latex](P.west) -- (H.east);
\draw[ultra thick, dotted](M.south) -- (N.north);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I appreciate your help, I have looked at your scripts in some parts, not all, but I have also thought about how to do it.